# CSS div container align vertical

Tags: html, css

I have one div container. This container should be vertical align. 
Here is my Code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
}

.text{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
}
nav{
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: white;
}

ul{
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

..................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: vertical-align left || center || right???

Comment: I dont know how to use it. i tryed it

Comment: No, I'm saying do you want to center the div in the middle of the screen?

Comment: Look at this: [Vertical align anything with just 3 lines of CSS](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [Click here for JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2kyjqyk/1/)

```
.text {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:middle` to the `div`.

Comment: Have you tried this? This doesn't work. He wants to add the div to the center of the screen.