# display slide div in center

Tags: html, css

I want to display the slide show in center of div tag where I marked it as black.But now it displayed n top-left corner.

```css
 .slide{background-image:url("samples.jpg") ;
        background-size: 100% ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:500px; 
  border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
 }
 .point_556492{
 padding:45px,0px;  
border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
   float: center;
   height:150px;
   border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    width:50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="slide">
       <div class="point_556492"> sample</div>
             
     </div>
```

Comment: just horizontally centered or in both dimensions?

Comment: I answered something similar to this yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727146/css-div-container-align-vertical/28727452

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are centering the div vertically **and** horizontally.

Note...this works for any size internal div.

```css
.slide {
    background-image:url("samples.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.point_556492 {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%); /* add your required prefixes */
    padding:45px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    /* float: center; no such property */
    height:150px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    width:50%;

}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
    <div class="point_556492">sample</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, the div is centered vertically but not horizontally.

Comment: Looks centered to me..of course I haven't prefixed the transform so it might be a browser issue.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't see you were using `transform`

Comment: still I have problem with this

Comment: That doesn't explain what the 'problem' is...perhaps you could clarify as it works in Chrome, IE11 & Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd suggest using flexbox or Paulie_D's solution, but in case you need to support older browsers, here's a different solution,
add these styles to your inner div:

```
position:relative;
top: 50%;
margin: -75px auto; /* half the height of inner div */
```

PRO: Supports even older browsers like IE8. if you need that
CON: You need to know the height of either the inner or the outer div to set your margin accordingly. In case you know the height of the other div, you have to adjust that example a bit.

Here's a full example based on your code

```css
 .slide{background-image:url("samples.jpg") ;
    background-size: 100% ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:500px; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
 }
 .point_556492{
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   margin: -75px auto;
   padding:45px,0px;  
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 5px;
   height:150px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 5px;
   width:50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div class="point_556492"> sample</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` to the `.slide` so that you can position `.point_556492` centrally within it by giving it an absolute position of 0 all around and auto margins.

```css
 .slide{background-image:url("samples.jpg") ;
    background-size: 100% ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:500px; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    position:relative;                /* <- add this */
 }
 .point_556492{
    padding:45px,0px;  
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    /* float: center; */              /* <- remove this */
    position:absolute;                /* <- position absolutely */
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; /* <- at zero all around */
    margin:auto;                      /* <- so the auto margin will centre it both horizontally and vertically */
    height:150px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    width:50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="slide">
    <div class="point_556492"> sample</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution avoids the need for `transform:translate` which isn't supported in <IE9 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this - `margin:0 auto`

```
<div class="slide">
<div class="point_556492" style="margin:0 auto;"> sample</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct, but doesn't centre it vertically.